# android.os.DeadObjectException at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.x

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am facing this problem I don't have any scenario it reported as 20 times:
I have the youtube jar as the version number is:

**Manifest-Version**: 1.0

**Name**: com/google/android/youtube/player

**Specification-Title**: YouTube Android Player API

**Specification-Version**: 1.2.2

**Specification-Vendor**: Google Inc

**Created-By**: 1.8.0-google-v7 (Google Inc.)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.DeadObjectException
       at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.x(SourceFile:209)
       at hwe.w(SourceFile:305)
       at abpk.onTransact(SourceFile:228)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.d$a$a.r(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.s.h(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.e(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1238)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3175)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3234)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java)
       at com.google.android.apps.youtube.embeddedplayer.service.service.jar.IApiPlayerService$Stub$Proxy.k(SourceFile:289)
       at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.x(SourceFile:207)
       at hwe.w(SourceFile:305)
       at abpk.onTransact(SourceFile:228)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.d$a$a.r(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.s.h(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.e(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1238)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3175)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3234)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an internal issue in YouTube player and will be solved in next release,
you can track the issue here :

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35172585

This Exception occurred if the **YoutubePlayer** has been released

According to the [Youtube SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason)  on errors:

> public static final YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason UNEXPECTED_SERVICE_DISCONNECTION
>
> Playback has been canceled and the player has been released due to an unexpected disconnection from the YouTube API service. Any further calls to this player instance will result in errors, a new player instance must be created to re-enable playback.

So to avoid this exception you have put your calls (like `youtubePlayer.loadVideo()`, `cueVideo()`, `getCurrentTimeMillis()` etc.) in a try catch block and catch the **IllegalStateException** exception.

To create a new instance of the **YoutubePlayer** just call the `initialize()` method in the catch block.

Example:

```
 if (youtubePlayer != null) {
        try {
            youtubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            initialize(API_KEY, this);
        }
    }
```

This is worked well for me