# Youtube player crash exception on Resume of activity in Android

Tags: android, youtube, crash, onresume

I added youtube player, for streaming videos. Video pauses when app is in background & resume on comes in foreground.
But in some cases it's crashed, when comes Resume state.
PFB screenshot of crashalytics :
[image]

It's showing dead object found on Resume of activity.

Here is my Youtube player activity code:

```
   @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("#ScreenONOFF","onDestroy" );
    YouTubeShareClass.getInstance().showInterestialAd(this,"Video Player");

    if (youTubePlayer != null) {
        youTubePlayer.release();
        youTubePlayer = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (youTubePlayer != null && videoID != null) {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoID,currentPlayerTime);
        youTubePlayer.play();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (youTubePlayer != null) {
        if(youTubePlayer.isPlaying()) {
           currentPlayerTime = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
            youTubePlayer.pause();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (videoID != null) {
        youTubePlayer = player;
        if (youTubePlayer != null && mReceiver != null) {
            if (wasRestored) {
                player.play();
            } else {
                try {
                    player.loadVideo(videoID,0);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    youTubeView.initialize(YouTubeConstants.youtube_API_key, this);
                }
            }
            mReceiver.player = player;
            player.setFullscreen(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. For me is complicated to reproduce the error although I found a google tracker for the issue (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35172585).

Quoting this answer ([android.os.DeadObjectException at com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215998/android-os-deadobjectexception-at-com-google-android-youtube-api-jar-client-remo/46811448#46811448)) Google has something to say about the error:

> public static final YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason UNEXPECTED_SERVICE_DISCONNECTION
>
> Playback has been canceled and the player has been released due to an unexpected disconnection from the YouTube API service. Any further calls to this player instance will result in errors, a new player instance must be created to re-enable playback.

I cannot verify 100% that this solution is valid because I can't reproduce the error, but this might help:

```
if(ytPlayer != null) {
    try {
        ytPlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }
}
```